# How to disable and throw exception for multiple endpoint in different Controller in Spring with annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a code like :-

```
public interface OrderControler {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/trackinginfo",
          produces = "application/json", 
          method = RequestMethod.GET)

          // Disabling with annotation
          default ResponseEntity<String> getTrackingInfo()  {...}

          default ResponseEntity<String> getTrackingInfo()  {...}
  }

}

public interface OrderControler {

  // Disabling with annotation
  @RequestMapping(value = "/orderDetails",
          produces = "application/json", 
          method = RequestMethod.GET)
      
          default ResponseEntity<String> getorderDetails()
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/orderMethods",
          produces = "application/json", 
          method = RequestMethod.GET)
      
          default ResponseEntity<String> getorderMethod() {...}
  }

}
```

I want to implementate an annotation which throws 503 error for some of the endpoints in the different controller. I dont want to write if and else conditions to throw the Exceptions for 503 in each disabled endpoint.

Thanks

Comment: And you have tried? Or are you expecting that we weite all your code for you?

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it, of course, but why?**
make a package on your project name like Exception.
after it, make the java class named it what is you need an exception.
example : notFoundException

```
package com.class3.poinofsaleclass3.exception;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.FOUND)
public class NotFoundException extends RuntimeException{
public  NotFoundException (String message){
        super(message);
}}
```

after it you can throw new `NotFoundException` your coding place

```
public static void checkNegative(int n) {
try {
    int[] a = new int[n];
} catch (NegativeArraySizeException e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can custom a annotation(examples CheckEndpointsAnnotion), write on these controlers. write a Interceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter ,overwrite this method

```
preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
```

you can get the annotion or not  by

```
 HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
    CheckEndpointsAnnotion checkAnnotation = handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(CheckEndpointsAnnotion.class);
```